# Questions About Pivoting Data in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Please help us!

Possible use of pivot?

That converts this:

```
Company Division    SubDivision Al2   ledger    year    valuetype   value
888     Marathon    a           NULL  5131000   2014    Fact       -2411
888     Marathon    a           NULL  5131000   2014    Fact       -4180
888     Marathon    a           NULL  5131000   2014    Fact       -787
888     Marathon    a           NULL  5131000   2015    Plan       -2000
888     Marathon    a           NULL  5131000   2015    Fact       -5397
```

this:

```
Comp    Div         SubDiv  Al2   ledger    year    vtype   Fact2014    Fact2015    Plan2015
888     Marathon    a       NULL 5131000    2014    Fact    -7378       -5397      -2000
```

Comment: Looks like it should be possible.   Try PIVOT on valuetype+year.

Comment: Pivot is used, but could not remember the concatenation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here try this out:

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE
(
Company INT,
Division VARCHAR(25),
SubDivision CHAR(1),
Al2 INT,
ledger INT,
[year] INT,
valuetype VARCHAR(10),
value INT
);

INSERT INTO @yourTable
VALUES ('888','Marathon','a',NULL,'5131000','2014','Fact','-2411'),
('888','Marathon','a',NULL,'5131000','2014','Fact','-4180'),
('888','Marathon','a',NULL,'5131000','2014','Fact','-787'),
('888','Marathon','a',NULL,'5131000','2015','Plan','-2000'),
('888','Marathon','a',NULL,'5131000','2015','Fact','-5397');

SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT  Company,
            Division,
            SubDivision,
            Al2,
            Ledger,
            value,
            CONCAT(valuetype,[year]) valueType_Year
    FROM @yourTable
) A
PIVOT
(
    MAX(value) FOR valueType_Year IN([Fact2014],[Fact2015],[Plan2015])
) pvt
```

Results:

```
Company     Division                  SubDivision Al2         Ledger      Fact2014    Fact2015    Plan2015
----------- ------------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
888         Marathon                  a           NULL        5131000     -787        -5397       -2000
```